# Debugging AngularJS Routes in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, webstorm

I love the AngularJS integration with WebStorm.  It makes development of angular apps even quicker and snappier than ever.  However, I'm struggling to get Chrome debugging to work.  Does anyone know if this is supported through the AngularJS plugin?

I've setup the javascript debugger, and I get the Chrome extension to connect to WebStorm.  I then navigate to my app's main page (the login page) and any breakpoints on that page work great.  But then as soon as I change to any other route in the app, the breakpoints and variable inspection just stop working.

I imagine that's because WebStorm doesn't know which javascript file (or angular module) is being executed after the route changes.  Does anyone know if there is a way to configure this to make it work?  It would be really great to be able to inspect/debug my `$scope` variables, bindings, services/directives, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

PS. I'm currently using the WebStorm 8 EAP, but I also have WebStorm 7 available.

**UPDATE:** After some more googling, I found that you have to setup the `Run/Debug Configurations` within WebStorm.  My problem was that I had the wrong `Remote URL` for my project's root folder.  After changing that configuration, it works great :)

Comment: works for me. Can you provide a sample project (configured for debugging, with the corresponding run configurations) that shows up the issue?

Comment: I was able to figure it out after some more googling.  Sorry.  I meant to come back and close this question, but I forgot.  Thanks for taking the time to look at it though.